# How to make a button change the frame and call a function (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a piece of code that uses frames in tkinter. When the back button is pressed I want the frame to change and a function to destroy a label be called. Currently I have the following code:

```
b2=Button(self, text="Back", command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
b2.pack()
```

which changes the frame when the button is pressed.

I tried to make a new function and call that when the button is pressed instead of the controller:

```
def moveOn(self):
    controller.show_frame("StartPage")
    self.l6.destroy()
```

but I get the error that controller isn't defined.

How do I fix my problem, or is there a different better way to do this?

If I need to provide any more code please let me know.

Comment: Where is the `controller` defined? Show the order of the definitions of your classes and functions.

Answer (score 0):

With the proposed source code, if the variable `controller` in the class having the `b2=Button(...)` and not in the class having the `moveOn()`, it is time to reuse a `command=lambda: ...` instead of the supposed `command=self.moveOn`.

> The variable `controller` is certainly one of the arguments of the
>   class `__init__()` constructor. So, it is a local variable which
>   doesn't exit until the function `moveOn()` is called.

**Solution 1** - use a `command=lambda:` to send the `constroller` to the function `moveOn()`.

> First modify the `command` of "Back" `Button`.

```
b2=Button(self, text="Back", command=lambda: self.moveOn(controller))
b2.pack()
```

Instead of:

```
b2=Button(self, text="Back", command=self.moveOn)
b2.pack()
```

> Then add `controller` as `moveOn()` argument.

```
def moveOn(self,controller):
    controller.show_frame(LoginPage)
    self.l6.destroy()
```

Instead of:

```
def moveOn(self):
    controller.show_frame("StartPage")
    self.l6.destroy()
```

**Solution 2** - store the argument `controller` as a class variable.

> In the `__init__()` function of the class having the `b2=Button(...)`.

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    ...
    self.controller = controller
    ...
```

> In the `moveOn()` use that variable:

```
def moveOn(self,controller):
    self.controller.show_frame(LoginPage)
    self.l6.destroy()
```